# WMI types conversion issue

Tags: c++, qt, wmi, ram, windows

I want to get ram slots memory and convert it to GB. I use WMI, Win32_PhysicalMemory class with property Capacity.

Code:

```
QString userRAMCapacity = QString::fromWCharArray(ramCapacity.bstrVal);
```

When using Qt function -

```
QString::fromWCharArray(ramCapacity.bstrVal);
```

I get proper ram slots memory capacity in bytes, but I can't convert it to GB. I tried to use another function -

```
QString::number(ramCapacity.uintVal),
```

it works but display the wrong memory amount. Please help to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `but I can't convert it to GB` why?

Comment: When converting to GB: userRAMCapacity = QString::fromWCharArray(ramCapacity.bstrVal) / (1024) / (1024) / (1024);

Error: error: C2678: binary '/': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'QString' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: exactly, because you are trying to convert a sting, convert it to a number first and then do the rest of the math

Comment: I know that I using the wrong type, but how to convert to number? When using QString::number(ramCapacity.uintVal) / (1024) / (1024) / (1024)  it shows not proper values.

Comment: see my  answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QString has [toInt()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt) method that you would need to apply before doing any math:

```
auto result = QString::fromWCharArray(ramCapacity.bstrVal). toLongLong() / (1024) / (1024) / (1024);
```

Comment: I tried your code, but in console when I print using qDebug() function, the result is "\u0000"
"\u0000"
"\u0000"
"\u0000"

Comment: when you print what?

Comment: Code:
QString userRAMCapacity = QString::fromWCharArray(ramCapacity.bstrVal).toInt() / (1024) / (1024) / (1024);
 qDebug() << userRAMCapacity;

Comment: but ist not QString you are getting, its `int`, declare it as `int`

Comment: int ramCapacity_GB = QString::fromWCharArray(ramCapacity.bstrVal).toInt() / (1024) / (1024) / (1024);
qDebug() << ramCapacity_GB;

This code shows 0 in console. Here is the image: http://i86.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0104/6a/3977d1b6885d881fc8f8759a7bc87d6a.png

Comment: what value do you get when printing just QString::fromWCharArray(ramCapacity.bstrVal) ?

Comment: Values are "8589934592"
"8589934592"
"8589934592"
"8589934592" bytes for 4 slots.

It should be 8 GB for 1 slot.

Comment: I also check values in cmd using wmic. 
Image:  http://i88.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0104/57/da524dc5ff288270fd08a8a386f3d557.png

Comment: ah sorry I changed my answer, int is overflowing, you need to use toLongLong()